# Multigraph enumeration with connection number limitation of nodes

Tags: number-theory, graph-theory, python

I need to generate multigraphs by several labeled nodes. Each node has a limitation of connection number, and they always higher or equal than 3.

For example:

```
{0: 3, 1: 3, 2: 4}
```

Nodes {0, 1} are adjacent with 3 edges respectively; node {2} is adjacent with 4 edges. The only one answer of the example is follow:

[The result of the example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2wcs.png)

I'm now using [NetworkX](https://networkx.github.io/) module of Python, it's using edge set as the expression of graphs. For the above image, it's expression is:

```
MutiGraph([(0, 1, 0), (0, 2, 0), (0, 2, 1), (1, 2, 0), (1, 2, 1)])
```

For more simpler, another expression implement on my Cython library is:

```
Graph([(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 2), (1, 2), (1, 2)])
```

As a newcomer of Graph Enumeration Algorithm, I'm now using recursive method that has terrible performance. There needs some improvements for complexity, such like permutation or combination methods.

Update:

With the method of create Diophantine Equations like this (where $n_{ij} = n_{ji}$ is the number of edges $\{i, j\}$):

$$
n_{01} + n_{02} = 3
\\
n_{01} + n_{12} = 3
\\
n_{02} + n_{12} = 4
$$

I'm not sure how to transform the multivariate equation into Hermite normal form.

Number of variables is $\frac{n(n - 1)}{2}$. In the bigger case, like `{0: 3, 1: 3, 2: 3, ..., 6: 3}` has 15 variables but only 6 equations, it's matrix after doing Gaussian elimination will become:

```
[[ 1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -3]
 [ 0 -1  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  3]
 [ 0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  1  1  0  3]
 [ 0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  0  1  0  1  3]
 [ 0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  0  1  1  3]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  6]]
```

Comment: Do you need to find *all* such graphs or just one?

Comment: @MishaLavrov Yes, I need all. Isomorphic graphs should be avoid.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have labeled vertices, this seems to me to more of a number theory problem than a graph theory problem. Let $n_{ij}=n_{ji}$ be the number of edges joining vertices  and . Then the example problem is simply to find all solutions to
$$\begin{align}n_{01}+n_{02}&=3\\n_{01}+n_{12}&=3\\n_{02}+n_{12}&=4\end{align}$$
in nonnegative integers.

If this is correct, look at "[Algorithms for Hermite and Smith Normal Matrices and Linear Diophantine Equations](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1971-25-116/S0025-5718-1971-0301909-X/S0025-5718-1971-0301909-X.pdf),"
by Gordon H. Bradley, Math. Comp. vol. 25  Number 116 (October 1971)

Comment: Well, $n_{01} + n_{12} = 3$ should be reasonable? This answer is close, but maybe I need a prototype of the Linear Diophantine algorithm.

Comment: I think the simple Diophantine algorithm similar with `itertools.product` in Python but has different max number (as same as the max number of $n_{ij}$ in its equations) during enumeration, it's that right?

Comment: Yes, that was a typo in my second equation.  What do you mean by a prototype of the algorithm?  It's explained in the paper.  You may be able to simplify it, though, because in your case all the coefficients are $1$ or $ 0.$  I'm not sure I understand your second comment.  Do you mean to try substituting all possible values for the variables?  That would far too inefficient, I think.